# Get To Android Pie bluetooth Settings Without Turning Them Off

Tags: 9.0-pie

Is there an EASY way to get the Bluetooth settings without turning them off?
The new shortcut in Pie sucks because it an on/off button
The old design allowed you to click on the name under the icon to get to the settings to just disconnect one item if needed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try long press on the shortcut icon, without lifting your finger until the new screen starts to appear.

On my Pixel 2, I was able to get to the Bluetooth Setting screen.

Answer (score 1):

Yes hold your finger on it. It also works for Wi-Fi.

(BTW I find it really inconvenient since the screen on my new phone is so slippery, it's hard to hold my finger on one spot. But that's what it is...)